# Declaration appears in the middle of Quick Help documentation

Tags: xcode, formatting, documentation, markup, xcode10

When I define an entity with and provide a documentation for it:

```
/**
 User Info:
 * `event` - the corresponding event.
 */
static let eventNotification = Notification.Name(rawValue: "MSGameEvent")
```

Quick Help displays it wrong:

[image]

As you can see, the doc is split into two parts (Summary and Discussion) with the Declaration stuffed in the middle. This makes the documentation barely readable (and hurts my perfectionism).

How can I make the quick help continuous?

Comment: **Off-topic:** Is there a way to make this documentation boiler-plate appear? I know the use of command + option + /, but that gives only single line comment.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, hold ⌥ and click the symbol with the left mouse button.